# Hyperledger Fabric Java SDK Use GRPCS for peer and orderer connections

Tags: ssl, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, tls1.2

I have a Spring Boot project using the fabric-java-sdk pointing to the BYFN network that I've stood up locally.

The BYFN network does not have a CA container.

I am trying to connect to the peer and orderer with grpcs since tls is enabled on my local BYFN network.  Grpc fails.

However, it appears that it doesn't like the CN or some other field in the cert presented by the peer during the initial TLS handshake.  I think it doesn't like that I am pointing to localhost for the grpcs url, but the CN is not 'localhost' in the cert presented by the peer, nor are there any 'localhost' SANs.  (This based on my weak understanding of TLS).

Am I missing something built into the Fabric Java SDK to get this to work?  Or maybe I need to add some config to the peer and orderer nodes so that their tls certs have 'localhost' SANs?

Code and trace below, thank you.

```
private static void initHfClient() throws Exception {
    hfClient = HFClient.createNewInstance();

    CryptoSuite cs = CryptoSuite.Factory.getCryptoSuite();
    hfClient.setCryptoSuite(cs);

    User context = new LocalUser();
    hfClient.setUserContext(context);

    Channel channel = hfClient.newChannel("mychannel");

    Peer p = hfClient.newPeer("peer0.org1.example.com", "grpcs://localhost:7051");
    channel.addPeer(p);
    channel.addOrderer(hfClient.newOrderer("orderer.example.com", "grpcs://localhost:7050"));
    channel.initialize();
}
```

Trace:

```
    org.hyperledger.fabric.sdk.exception.ProposalException: org.hyperledger.fabric.sdk.exception.TransactionException: org.hyperledger.fabric.sdk.exception.ProposalException: getConfigBlock for channel mychannel failed with peer peer0.org1.example.com.  Status FAILURE, details: Channel Channel{id: 1, name: mychannel} Sending proposal with transaction: 8d926388b9bc4d16e97260f0905076d8cce4abb5499c324d85cc012c82e534a2 to Peer{ id: 2, name: peer0.org1.example.com, channelName: mychannel, url: grpcs://localhost:7051} failed because of: gRPC failure=Status{code=UNAVAILABLE, description=io exception, cause=javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: General OpenSslEngine problem
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.ReferenceCountedOpenSslContext$AbstractCertificateVerifier.verify(ReferenceCountedOpenSslContext.java:665)
    at io.netty.internal.tcnative.SSL.readFromSSL(Native Method)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.ReferenceCountedOpenSslEngine.readPlaintextData(ReferenceCountedOpenSslEngine.java:565)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.ReferenceCountedOpenSslEngine.unwrap(ReferenceCountedOpenSslEngine.java:1114)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.ReferenceCountedOpenSslEngine.unwrap(ReferenceCountedOpenSslEngine.java:1226)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.ReferenceCountedOpenSslEngine.unwrap(ReferenceCountedOpenSslEngine.java:1269)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler$SslEngineType$1.unwrap(SslHandler.java:216)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.unwrap(SslHandler.java:1297)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.decodeJdkCompatible(SslHandler.java:1199)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.decode(SslHandler.java:1243)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.decodeRemovalReentryProtection(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:502)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:441)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:278)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:340)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1434)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:965)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:163)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:648)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:583)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:500)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:462)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:897)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.security.cert.CertificateException: No subject alternative DNS name matching localhost found.
    at sun.security.util.HostnameChecker.matchDNS(HostnameChecker.java:214)
    at sun.security.util.HostnameChecker.match(HostnameChecker.java:96)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkIdentity(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:455)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkIdentity(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:436)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:252)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:136)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.OpenSslTlsv13X509ExtendedTrustManager.checkServerTrusted(OpenSslTlsv13X509ExtendedTrustManager.java:239)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.ReferenceCountedOpenSslClientContext$ExtendedTrustManagerVerifyCallback.verify(ReferenceCountedOpenSslClientContext.java:242)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.ReferenceCountedOpenSslContext$AbstractCertificateVerifier.verify(ReferenceCountedOpenSslContext.java:661)
    ... 27 more
}
    at org.hyperledger.fabric.sdk.Channel.sendProposalToPeers(Channel.java:4059)
    at org.hyperledger.fabric.sdk.Channel.sendProposal(Channel.java:4030)
    at org.hyperledger.fabric.sdk.Channel.queryByChaincode(Channel.java:3940)
    at org.hyperledger.fabric.sdk.Channel.queryByChaincode(Channel.java:3926)
    at com.comcast.iotledger.fabricAPI.services.FabricIotledgerService.checkAuth(FabricIotledgerService.java:37)
    at com.comcast.iotledger.fabricAPI.controllers.MainController.checkAuth(MainController.java:41)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:189)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:102)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:895)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:800)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1038)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:942)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1005)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:897)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:92)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:93)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:490)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:791)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1417)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.hyperledger.fabric.sdk.exception.TransactionException: org.hyperledger.fabric.sdk.exception.ProposalException: getConfigBlock for channel mychannel failed with peer peer0.org1.example.com.  Status FAILURE, details: Channel Channel{id: 1, name: mychannel} Sending proposal with transaction: 8d926388b9bc4d16e97260f0905076d8cce4abb5499c324d85cc012c82e534a2 to Peer{ id: 2, name: peer0.org1.example.com, channelName: mychannel, url: grpcs://localhost:7051} failed because of: gRPC failure=Status{code=UNAVAILABLE, description=io exception, cause=javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: General OpenSslEngine problem
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.ReferenceCountedOpenSslContext$AbstractCertificateVerifier.verify(ReferenceCountedOpenSslContext.java:665)
    at io.netty.internal.tcnative.SSL.readFromSSL(Native Method)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.ReferenceCountedOpenSslEngine.readPlaintextData(ReferenceCountedOpenSslEngine.java:565)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.ReferenceCountedOpenSslEngine.unwrap(ReferenceCountedOpenSslEngine.java:1114)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.ReferenceCountedOpenSslEngine.unwrap(ReferenceCountedOpenSslEngine.java:1226)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.ReferenceCountedOpenSslEngine.unwrap(ReferenceCountedOpenSslEngine.java:1269)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler$SslEngineType$1.unwrap(SslHandler.java:216)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.unwrap(SslHandler.java:1297)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.decodeJdkCompatible(SslHandler.java:1199)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.decode(SslHandler.java:1243)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.decodeRemovalReentryProtection(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:502)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:441)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:278)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:340)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1434)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:965)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:163)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:648)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:583)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:500)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:462)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:897)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.security.cert.CertificateException: No subject alternative DNS name matching localhost found.
    at sun.security.util.HostnameChecker.matchDNS(HostnameChecker.java:214)
    at sun.security.util.HostnameChecker.match(HostnameChecker.java:96)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkIdentity(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:455)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkIdentity(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:436)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:252)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:136)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.OpenSslTlsv13X509ExtendedTrustManager.checkServerTrusted(OpenSslTlsv13X509ExtendedTrustManager.java:239)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.ReferenceCountedOpenSslClientContext$ExtendedTrustManagerVerifyCallback.verify(ReferenceCountedOpenSslClientContext.java:242)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.ReferenceCountedOpenSslContext$AbstractCertificateVerifier.verify(ReferenceCountedOpenSslContext.java:661)
    ... 27 more
}
    at org.hyperledger.fabric.sdk.Channel.parseConfigBlock(Channel.java:1796)
    at org.hyperledger.fabric.sdk.Channel.loadCACertificates(Channel.java:1616)
    at org.hyperledger.fabric.sdk.Channel.sendProposalToPeers(Channel.java:4057)
    ... 59 more
Caused by: org.hyperledger.fabric.sdk.exception.ProposalException: getConfigBlock for channel mychannel failed with peer peer0.org1.example.com.  Status FAILURE, details: Channel Channel{id: 1, name: mychannel} Sending proposal with transaction: 8d926388b9bc4d16e97260f0905076d8cce4abb5499c324d85cc012c82e534a2 to Peer{ id: 2, name: peer0.org1.example.com, channelName: mychannel, url: grpcs://localhost:7051} failed because of: gRPC failure=Status{code=UNAVAILABLE, description=io exception, cause=javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: General OpenSslEngine problem
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.ReferenceCountedOpenSslContext$AbstractCertificateVerifier.verify(ReferenceCountedOpenSslContext.java:665)
    at io.netty.internal.tcnative.SSL.readFromSSL(Native Method)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.ReferenceCountedOpenSslEngine.readPlaintextData(ReferenceCountedOpenSslEngine.java:565)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.ReferenceCountedOpenSslEngine.unwrap(ReferenceCountedOpenSslEngine.java:1114)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.ReferenceCountedOpenSslEngine.unwrap(ReferenceCountedOpenSslEngine.java:1226)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.ReferenceCountedOpenSslEngine.unwrap(ReferenceCountedOpenSslEngine.java:1269)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler$SslEngineType$1.unwrap(SslHandler.java:216)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.unwrap(SslHandler.java:1297)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.decodeJdkCompatible(SslHandler.java:1199)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.decode(SslHandler.java:1243)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.decodeRemovalReentryProtection(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:502)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:441)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:278)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:340)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1434)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:965)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:163)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:648)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:583)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:500)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:462)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:897)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.security.cert.CertificateException: No subject alternative DNS name matching localhost found.
    at sun.security.util.HostnameChecker.matchDNS(HostnameChecker.java:214)
    at sun.security.util.HostnameChecker.match(HostnameChecker.java:96)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkIdentity(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:455)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkIdentity(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:436)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:252)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:136)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.OpenSslTlsv13X509ExtendedTrustManager.checkServerTrusted(OpenSslTlsv13X509ExtendedTrustManager.java:239)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.ReferenceCountedOpenSslClientContext$ExtendedTrustManagerVerifyCallback.verify(ReferenceCountedOpenSslClientContext.java:242)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.ReferenceCountedOpenSslContext$AbstractCertificateVerifier.verify(ReferenceCountedOpenSslContext.java:661)
    ... 27 more
}
    at org.hyperledger.fabric.sdk.Channel.getConfigBlock(Channel.java:867)
    at org.hyperledger.fabric.sdk.Channel.parseConfigBlock(Channel.java:1779)
    ... 61 more
```

Comment: You'll need to override the host your client thinks it's connecting to in order to use TLS with "localhost". If you were directly using a gRPC client (although I don't see grpc anywhere in the stacktrace posted), you would do this via https://grpc.io/grpc-java/javadoc/io/grpc/ManagedChannelBuilder.html#overrideAuthority-java.lang.String-

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally figured it out.  Here's the high level for getting this to work:

- The cryptogen tool from Fabric consumes a yaml file, for me in `crypto-config.yaml`.  You can set SANs in there.  So I added "localhost" as a SAN for all peers and orderers.
- The JVM needs a custom truststore that accepts the certs that are going to be presented by the peer and orderer during grpcs tls handshake.  Use the Java keytool to create a truststore with the .crt files in: `crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer0.org1.example.com/tls` and `crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer.example.com/tls`.  Note that YMMV on the paths to the .crt files, and perhaps not all are required to be in the truststore to get it to work.  I just threw all of them in there.
- Pass the truststore to the JVM with `-Djava.net.ssl.trustStore=truststore.jks -Djava.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=changeit`, or in Spring like: `System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", pathToTrustStore) System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword", pw)`

Keytool create truststore instructions: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19509-01/820-3503/ggfka/index.html
(the aliases used when adding certs to the store don't appear to matter).

-- by request, here's an example of setting SANs in crypto-config.yaml:

```
# ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# "PeerOrgs" - Definition of organizations managing peer nodes
# ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
PeerOrgs:
  # ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
  # Org1
  # ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
  - Name: Org1
    Domain: example.com
    EnableNodeOUs: true
    # ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    # "Specs"
    # ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    # Uncomment this section to enable the explicit definition of hosts in your
    # configuration.  Most users will want to use Template, below
    #
    # Specs is an array of Spec entries.  Each Spec entry consists of two fields:
    #   - Hostname:   (Required) The desired hostname, sans the domain.
    #   - CommonName: (Optional) Specifies the template or explicit override for
    #                 the CN.  By default, this is the template:
    #
    #                              "{{.Hostname}}.{{.Domain}}"
    #
    #                 which obtains its values from the Spec.Hostname and
    #                 Org.Domain, respectively.
    # ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Specs:
      - Hostname: peer0
        CommonName: peer0.example.com # overrides Hostname-based FQDN set above
        SANS:
          - "localhost"
      - Hostname: peer1
        CommonName: peer1.example.com
        SANS:
          - "localhost"
```

Comment: Can you please share your crypto-config.yaml file that how dd you specify the SANS? Thanks

Comment: @BilalAhmedYaseen added example

Comment: Thanks @alex-totheroh. Didn't you add "localhost" under SANS? And, now how will these peers be accessed? As organisation names are different in SANS and CommonName.

Comment: @BilalAhmedYaseenYes you're right, the example I posted was for syntax only.  YMMV on actual values.  I've modified the SANs in the example, though.

Comment: I actually tried this but peers/orderers were still not accessible via localhost. So, I ended up adding entries in /etc/host file. In connection profile it works with localhost but in JAVA SDK you require actual name.