# Why am i getting TLS handshake error when i try to connect from hyperledger java-sdk to a blockchain in docker swarm?

Tags: java, sdk, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I've deployed the fabric simple-example structure (2 orgs with 2 peers, 2 CA and 1 orderer) using docker swarm(Tested, and working properly).  I've used a private network to connect every entity to each other, like this:

```
networks:
  bymn:
    external:
      name: fabric

           [.  .  .]

    networks:
      bymn:
        aliases:
          - peer1.org2.example.com
```

I'm trying to connect myself, with this java code, to the blockchain(channel):

```
 Path networkConfigPath = Paths.get("./networkConfig.json");

 Gateway.Builder builder = Gateway.createBuilder();
 builder.identity(wallet,"appUser").networkConfig(networkConfigPath).discovery(true);

 // create a gateway connection
 try (Gateway gateway = builder.connect()) {
    // get the network and contract
    Network network = gateway.getNetwork("channel");
    System.out.println("Sucsesfully created connection with blockchain with channelName: channel");
...
```

appUser was created properly, with no errors, using this 2 classes from the fabric-samples Github:
[EnrollAdmin.java](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/blob/master/fabcar/java/src/main/java/org/example/EnrollAdmin.java)
[RegisterUser.java](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/blob/master/fabcar/java/src/main/java/org/example/RegisterUser.java)

Contents of `networkConfig.json`:

```
{
  "name" : "umu.fabric",
  "description" : "Connection profile for umu 2orgs-fabric-blockchain test",
  "version" : "1.0.0",
  "client" : {
    "organization" : "Org1",
    "connection" : {
      "timeout" : {
        "peer" : {
          "endorser" : 3000
        },
        "orderer" : 3000
      }
    }
  },
  "channels" : {
    "channel" : {
      "orderers" : [ "orderer.example.com" ],
      "peers" : {
        "peer1.org1.example.com" : {
          "endorsingPeer" : true,
          "chaincodeQuery" : true,
          "ledgerQuery" : true,
          "eventSource" : true
        },
        "peer0.org1.example.com" : {
          "endorsingPeer" : true,
          "chaincodeQuery" : true,
          "ledgerQuery" : true,
          "eventSource" : true
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "organizations" : {
    "Org1" : {
      "mspid" : "Org1MSP",
      "peers" : [ "peer0.org1.example.com", "peer1.org1.example.com" ],
      "certificateAuthorities" : [ "ca.org1.example.com" ]
    },
    "Org2" : {
      "mspid" : "Org2MSP",
      "peers" : [ "peer0.org2.example.com", "peer1.org2.example.com" ],
      "certificateAuthorities" : [ "ca.org2.example.com" ]
    }
  },
  "orderers" : {
    "orderer.example.com" : {
      "url" : "grpcs://orderer.example.com:7050"
    }
  },
  "peers" : {
    "peer0.org1.example.com" : {
      "url" : "grpcs://peer0.org1.example.com:7051"
    },
    "peer1.org1.example.com" : {
      "url" : "grpcs://peer1.org1.example.com:7051"
    },
    "peer0.org2.example.com" : {
      "url" : "grpcs://peer0.org2.example.com:7051"
    },
    "peer1.org2.example.com" : {
      "url" : "grpcs://peer1.org2.example.com:7051"
    }
  },
  "certificateAuthorities" : {
    "ca.org2.example.com" : {
      "url" : "https://ca.org2.example.com:7054"
    },
    "ca.org1.example.com" : {
      "url" : "https://ca.org1.example.com:7054",
      "httpOptions" : {
        "verify" : false
      },
      "registrar" : [ {
        "enrollId" : "admin",
        "enrollSecret" : "adminpw"
      } ]
    }
  }
}
```

(Sorry for copying the entire the file but i'm too lost right now)

I'm getting the following **error** on the Peer logs:

```
TLS handshake failed with error remote error: tls: internal error server=PeerServer remoteaddress=X.X.X.X
```

and this is what I'm getting from Java:

```
2020-07-14T13:25:31.124894206Z Successfully enrolled user "admin" and imported it into the wallet
2020-07-14T13:25:31.414993872Z Successfully enrolled user "appUser" and imported it into the wallet
2020-07-14T13:25:32.446634370Z 13:25:32.430 [main] ERROR org.hyperledger.fabric.sdk.Channel - Channel Channel{id: 1, name: channel} Sending proposal with transaction: 3919e41a6303faf9d59a5c78d70364ef8df1a458f52cf8cd7659c7c19a2dec3c to Peer{ id: 4, name: peer0.org1.example.com, channelName: channel, url: grpcs://peer0.org1.example.com:7051, mspid: Org1MSP} failed because of: gRPC failure=Status{code=UNAVAILABLE, description=io exception
2020-07-14T13:25:32.446672215Z Channel Pipeline: [SslHandler#0, ProtocolNegotiators$ClientTlsHandler#0, WriteBufferingAndExceptionHandler#0, DefaultChannelPipeline$TailContext#0], cause=javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: General OpenSslEngine problem
2020-07-14T13:25:32.446679901Z  at io.netty.handler.ssl.ReferenceCountedOpenSslEngine.handshakeException(ReferenceCountedOpenSslEngine.java:1735)
2020-07-14T13:25:32.446686221Z  at io.netty.handler.ssl.ReferenceCountedOpenSslEngine.wrap(ReferenceCountedOpenSslEngine.java:775)
2020-07-14T13:25:32.446692373Z  at javax.net.ssl.SSLEngine.wrap(SSLEngine.java:509)
[...........]

2020-07-14T13:25:32.494862402Z Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
2020-07-14T13:25:32.494868350Z  at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:387)
2020-07-14T13:25:32.494873876Z  at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(PKIXValidator.java:292)
2020-07-14T13:25:32.494879383Z  at sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Validator.java:260)
2020-07-14T13:25:32.494884872Z  at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:324)
2020-07-14T13:25:32.494890328Z  at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:281)
2020-07-14T13:25:32.494895764Z  at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:136)
2020-07-14T13:25:32.494901281Z  at io.netty.handler.ssl.OpenSslTlsv13X509ExtendedTrustManager.checkServerTrusted(OpenSslTlsv13X509ExtendedTrustManager.java:223)
2020-07-14T13:25:32.494906971Z  at io.netty.handler.ssl.ReferenceCountedOpenSslClientContext$ExtendedTrustManagerVerifyCallback.verify(ReferenceCountedOpenSslClientContext.java:255)
2020-07-14T13:25:32.494912650Z  at io.netty.handler.ssl.ReferenceCountedOpenSslContext$AbstractCertificateVerifier.verify(ReferenceCountedOpenSslContext.java:701)
2020-07-14T13:25:32.494918288Z  at io.netty.internal.tcnative.SSL.readFromSSL(Native Method)
2020-07-14T13:25:32.494927598Z  at io.netty.handler.ssl.ReferenceCountedOpenSslEngine.readPlaintextData(ReferenceCountedOpenSslEngine.java:594)
2020-07-14T13:25:32.494933532Z  at io.netty.handler.ssl.ReferenceCountedOpenSslEngine.unwrap(ReferenceCountedOpenSslEngine.java:1179)
2020-07-14T13:25:32.494939139Z  at io.netty.handler.ssl.ReferenceCountedOpenSslEngine.unwrap(ReferenceCountedOpenSslEngine.java:1296)
2020-07-14T13:25:32.494944788Z  at io.netty.handler.ssl.ReferenceCountedOpenSslEngine.unwrap(ReferenceCountedOpenSslEngine.java:1339)
2020-07-14T13:25:32.494950326Z  at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler$SslEngineType$1.unwrap(SslHandler.java:206)
2020-07-14T13:25:32.494955832Z  at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.unwrap(SslHandler.java:1372)
2020-07-14T13:25:32.494961250Z  ... 21 more
2020-07-14T13:25:32.494966697Z Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
2020-07-14T13:25:32.494972350Z  at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.build(SunCertPathBuilder.java:141)
2020-07-14T13:25:32.494977910Z  at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(SunCertPathBuilder.java:126)
2020-07-14T13:25:32.494983467Z  at java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(CertPathBuilder.java:280)
2020-07-14T13:25:32.495008727Z  at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:382)
2020-07-14T13:25:32.495014147Z  ... 36 more
2020-07-14T13:25:32.495019299Z }
2020-07-14T13:25:32.495024348Z  at org.hyperledger.fabric.sdk.Channel.getConfigBlock(Channel.java:952) ~[jar.jar:?]
2020-07-14T13:25:32.495045286Z  at org.hyperledger.fabric.sdk.Channel.getConfigBlock(Channel.java:907) ~[jar.jar:?]
2020-07-14T13:25:32.495050298Z  at org.hyperledger.fabric.sdk.Channel.parseConfigBlock(Channel.java:1994) [jar.jar:?]
2020-07-14T13:25:32.495070605Z  at org.hyperledger.fabric.sdk.Channel.loadCACertificates(Channel.java:1831) [jar.jar:?]
2020-07-14T13:25:32.495075445Z  at org.hyperledger.fabric.sdk.Channel.initialize(Channel.java:1222) [jar.jar:?]
2020-07-14T13:25:32.495080259Z  at org.hyperledger.fabric.gateway.impl.NetworkImpl.initializeChannel(NetworkImpl.java:59) [jar.jar:?]
2020-07-14T13:25:32.495100248Z  at org.hyperledger.fabric.gateway.impl.NetworkImpl.<init>(NetworkImpl.java:50) [jar.jar:?]
2020-07-14T13:25:32.495105836Z  at org.hyperledger.fabric.gateway.impl.GatewayImpl.getNetwork(GatewayImpl.java:252) [jar.jar:?]
2020-07-14T13:25:32.495110888Z  at org.umu.controllers.BlockchainController.runApp(BlockchainController.java:50) [jar.jar:?]
2020-07-14T13:25:32.495115947Z  at org.umu.controllers.BlockchainController.main(BlockchainController.java:35) [jar.jar:?]
2020-07-14T13:25:32.630988706Z Sucsesfully created connection with blockchain with channelName: channel
```

**Solutions?** I've seen in several answers to put the SANS to the peers. So I put it like this:

```
PeerOrgs:
  - Name: Org1
[.............]
    Specs:
      - Hostname: peer0
        CommonName: peer0.org1.example.com # overrides Hostname-based FQDN set above
        SANS:
          - "peer0.org1.example.com"
          - "peer0"
[.............]
```

Verifying with the openssl command:

```
openssl x509 -in crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer0.org1.example.com/tls/server.crt -text -noout
```

```
[.....]
X509v3 Subject Alternative Name: 
                DNS:peer0.org1.example.com, DNS:peer0, DNS:peer0.org1.example.com, DNS:peer0, DNS:localhost, DNS:peer0.org1.example.com, DNS:peer0, DNS:peer0.org1.example.com, DNS:peer0, DNS:localhost, DNS:peer0.org1.example.com, DNS:peer0, DNS:peer0.org1.example.com, DNS:peer0, DNS:localhost, DNS:peer0.org1.example.com, DNS:peer0, DNS:peer0.org1.example.com, DNS:peer0, DNS:localhost, DNS:peer0.org1.example.com, DNS:peer0, DNS:peer0.org1.example.com, DNS:peer0, DNS:localhost
    Signature Algorithm: ecdsa-with-SHA256
[.....]
```

I don't know what else to do.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I was having the same problem as [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53625506/hyperledger-fabric-java-sdk-use-grpcs-for-peer-and-orderer-connections/53676602?r=SearchResults&s=2%7C14.4806#53676602).

I needed to add the  certificate files (.pem or .crt files) to the jvm truststore.

```
sudo keytool -import -file crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer0.org1.example.com/tls/server.crt -alias peer0.org1.example.com -keystore /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/security/cacerts -storepass changeit
sudo keytool -import -file crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer1.org1.example.com/tls/server.crt -alias peer1.org1.example.com -keystore /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/security/cacerts -storepass changeit
sudo keytool -import -file crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/peers/peer1.org2.example.com/tls/server.crt -alias peer1.org2.example.com -keystore /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/security/cacerts -storepass changeit
sudo keytool -import -file crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/peers/peer0.org2.example.com/tls/server.crt -alias peer0.org2.example.com -keystore /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/security/cacerts -storepass changeit
sudo keytool -import -file crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer.example.com/tls/server.crt  -alias orderer.example.com -keystore /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/security/cacerts -storepass changeit
```

Comment: HI. I am having same problem (also with Fabric 2.2.2). I have imported both the peer certificate and the orderer one, along with the ca certificate for the peer. It won't solve it. Any idea how to diagnose what is the path that the JDK is looking for so I can determine which is the missing certificate? Thanks.